# My jekyll site on github is not showing my sass (scss)

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

I locally made a jekyll site which works perfectly. Now that I uploaded it to github it suddenly doesn't use any scss of mine anymore. In my wrapper.html layout (which I use a layout for the other layouts) I have included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/assets/css/main.css' | absolute_url }}" >
```

in assets/css/main.css is:

```
---
---
@import "stylesheet";
```

And _stylesheet.scss is in _sass/_stylesheet.scss. Let me know if more information is needed! What is going wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Now that I uploaded it to github` you mean a `.github.io` website right ?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant! :)

Comment: A repository url can be useful to debug.

Comment: Try to remove the leading slash, try using `assets/css/main.css`. Had the same issue yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

With Jekyll the two main problems for beginners are:

1. how the theme works/where to find its files and
2. how basurls/relative urls work.

This problem is clearly the latter. Github Pages requires a baseurl, so you cannot link to the domain root. Therefore the starting slash is incorrect. This should work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/assets/css/main.css' | prepend: site.baseurl }}" >
```

More info for Jekyll beginners can be found in this [Jekyll Conference talk](https://www.usecue.com/blog/speaking-at-jekyllconf2019/).